# How to ensure that a partial have a given field with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings, react-native-flatlist, typescript-partial

I have a type "Post" as follow:

```js
interface Post {
  id?: string
  title: string
  content: string
  tags?: string[]
}
```

I need to use it in a React Native flatlist, where the id is needed. In this case the id is fetched.

```
<FlatList
  data={posts as Array<Partial<Post>>}
  renderItem={({ item }: { item: Partial<Post> }) => <ContentListItem post={item} />}
  keyExtractor={(item: Partial<Post>) => item.id}
  ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
/>
```

There **keyExtractor** is underlined with:

```
Type '(item: Partial<Post>) => string | undefined' is not assignable to type '(item: Partial<Post>, index: number) => string'.
```

I tried to change keyExtractor={(item: Partial) => item.id} to:

```
keyExtractor={(item: {id: string} & Partial<Post>) => item.id}
```

There **data** is underlined with:

```
Type 'Partial<Post>[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly ({ id: string; } & Partial<Post>)[]'.
```

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came to use an exclamation mark:

```
keyExtractor={(item: Partial<Post>) => item.id!}
```